# npm Slugify installation

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, slugify

When I try to install Slugify using `npm i slugify`, I get an error saying :-

```
C:\Users\2217445\OneDrive - Cognizant\Desktop\Nodej\natures> npm i slugify     
npm WARN natures@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path C:\Users\2217445\OneDrive - Cognizant\Desktop\Nodej\natures\node_modules\@humanwhocodes\config-array\node_modules\ms
npm ERR! dest C:\Users\2217445\OneDrive - Cognizant\Desktop\Nodej\natures\node_modules\@humanwhocodes\config-array\node_modules\.ms.DELETE
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\2217445\OneDrive - Cognizant\Desktop\Nodej\natures\node_modules\@humanwhocodes\config-array\node_modules\ms' -> 'C:\Users\2217445\OneDrive - Cognizant\Desktop\Nodej\natures\node_modules\@humanwhocodes\config-array\node_modules\.ms.DELETE'
npm ERR! dest C:\Users\2217445\OneDrive - Cognizant\Desktop\Nodej\natures\node_modules\@humanwhocodes\config-array\node_modules\.ms.DELETE
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\2217445\OneDrive - Cognizant\Desktop\Nodej\natures\node_modules\@humanwhocodes\config-array\node_modules\ms' -> 'C:\Users\2217445\OneDrive - Cognizant\Desktop\Nodej\natures\node_modules\@humanwhocodes\config-array\node_modules\.ms.DELETE'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\2217445\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2023-06-15T07_05_54_887Z-debug.log
PS C:\Users\2217445\OneDrive - Cognizant\Desktop\Nodej\natures>
```

I'm working on natures directory, once I try to install slugify,
I get an warn of No repository field.
And an error saying This is related to npm not being able to find a file